# Modificar sys.path o $PYTHONPATH para que mi app trabaje con otra version python y sus site-packages

Tags: python, bash, flask, rutas, app

Tengo una App Flask desplegada en un servidor, la cual está tratando de utilizar la versión de *Python3.10* y sus site-packages instalados.

Ésta versión la eliminé por ciertos motivos y **quisiera que la ruta cambie a la versión anterior** ya instalada ***(Python 3.9)***

Desde la terminal Linux lanzo el comando: `python3 -m site --user-site` y recibo:

> /home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages

Curioso ya que supuestamente eliminé dicha version (o no correctamente).
Y dentro de la **consola python**, cuando lanzo el comando: `print(sys.path)` obtengo la siguiente ruta:

> ['', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9',
> '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib/python39.zip',
> '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib/python3.9',
> '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload',
> '/home/xxxxx/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages']

**¿Puede que me falte añadir algo en el primer elemento de la lista?** ([**''**, '/usr...]

En el fichero **pyvenv.cfg** tengo:

> home = /usr/local/bin  include-system-site-packages = true  version =
> 3.9.2

Y en el fichero **bashrc** añadí:

> **export PATH=$PATH**:/apps/venv/lib/python3.9 **export
> PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH**:/usr/local/lib/python3.9

Mi App no consigue funcionar ya que todavía trata de buscar las librerías de la version 3.10 y necesito configurar para que busque las de la 3.9...

Tambien, cuando trato de eliminar Python3.10 con `sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python3.10` obtengo esto:

> Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
> information... Done Note, selecting 'postgresql-plpython3-10' for
> regex 'python3.10' Package 'postgresql-plpython3-10' is not installed,
> so not removed 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 48 not
> upgraded.

**¿Algún consejo - ayuda?**

Comment: debian? centos? arch?

Comment: Description: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: deberias trabajar con virtual environments. para cada app deberias tener un virtual environment distinto donde le puedes instalar la version de python y librerias que la app necesite. No modifiques el path ni la version de python del sistema. Crea un virtual environment y ejecuta la app allí.

Comment: tan sólo tengo una app en ese servidor... y tambien probé a usar un virtual environment y no consigo que utilice la version que quiero...

Comment: cómo podría modificar la ruta: (/home/xxxx/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages) que obtengo al lanzar (python3 -m site --user-site) ??

Comment: recordas como fue q pasaste de python 3.6 a 3.10 ? podes probar `sudo dpkg-reconfigure python3` a ver q ondas, de paso ver si  `sudo update-alternatives --config python` tiene la 3.6 ( default de ubuntu 18 ) y las otras

Comment: si, directamente instalé la version 3.10 junto con sus modulos y librerías que necesitaba... Y al ejecutar el comando `sudo dpkg-reconfigure python3` obtengo: running python rtupdate hooks for python3.6...
running python post-rtupdate hooks for python3.6...
pero en update-alternatives no tengo ninguna version. 
Continúo con /home/xxxx/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages